# RabbitMQ - Clustering & Client Connections

Tags: rabbitmq

Hoping someone might be able to give me some guidance on this. I have setup a RabbitMQ cluster on 3 nodes.
- Node1 (Master), Node2 and Node3

The part I can't figure out is I cannot find any information about what happens if Master goes down, what is the client pointing to?

If Node1 goes down, then surely the clients which are configured to point to Node1 will not be able to automatically fail-over to whatever becomes the new master?

My idea was to setup a load balancer which detects which node is master and only ever redirects requests to that node?

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If clients are only capable of connecting to one node, and that node goes down, clients will lose connectivity.  You need (as you surmise) some kind of setup whereby either:

- you place a load-balancer in front of the nodes, and the clients connect only to the load-balancer; OR
- the clients can connect to any of the available nodes, trying each in turn.

Whichever solution, there is no need to direct all client traffic to the master node.  Clients nodes can connect to either a master or slave broker.

Answer (score 4):

Spring amqp helps in solving this easily. It provides the failover mechanism out of the box. You can just configure the address of the nodes with comma separated and pass it to addresses parameter while creating the connection factory.

For eg:

```
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" addresses="192.168.1.2:5672,192.168.1.3:5672" username="${rabbitmq.username}"
                           connection-factory="clientConnectionFactory"
                           cache-mode="${rabbit.cacheMode}"
                           channel-cache-size="${rabbit.channelCacheSize}"
                           password="${rabbitmq.password}" virtual-host="${rabbitmq.vhost}"/>
```

This way, when the first node goes down, the connection will be made to the second node.

Comment: Yea I had looked at several of these solutions but decided that I wanted one to abstract the need to list the actual RabbitMQ nodes in each of the clients/consumers.

Definitely worth looking at that though, thank-you

Answer (score 1):

At CloudAMQP we have one single URL to the cluster that clients connect to and we recommend to always configure clients to automatically reconnect on connection loss.

We have fail over and load balancing between nodes, and it's done over DNS, with a low TTL (30s).

https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-12-29-cloudamqp-plan-setup-pause-minority-mirrored-nodes-and-the-cap-theorem.html

Comment: Hey Johansson,

Thanks for that, I will take a look CloudAMQP is not one I have done any research on as of yet, but if it provides this mechanism it could be a good alternative. I shall research!

Thanks again